# varios select con un boton

Tags: php, javascript, html5, css3, tabla-dinámica

pues resulta que tengo una tabla de calificaciones:

```
<?php
  require_once "../crud/crud.php";
  $obj= new Crud();
  $datos=$obj->mostrarDatos();

  $tabla='<table class="table table-dark">
    <thead>
      <tr class="font-weight-bold">
        <td>Matricula</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Unidad I</td>
        <td>Examen</td>
        <td>Unidad II</td>
        <td>Examen</td>
        <td>Unidad III</td>
        <td>Examen</td>
        <td>Unidad IV</td>
        <td>Examen</td>
        <td>Unidad V</td>
        <td>Examen</td>
        <td>Calificar</td>
        <td>Editar</td>
        <td>Eliminar</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
      $datosTabla="";
      foreach ($datos as $key => $value){
        $datosTabla=$datosTabla.'<tr>
          <td>'.$value['matricula_alumno'] .'</td>
          <td>'.$value['nombre_alumno'] .'</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>  
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="calificarDatos " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#calificarModal">
              <i class="fas fa-pen-square"> </i>
            </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="obtenerDatos('.$value['id'] .')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#actualizarModal">
              <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
            </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminarDatos('.$value['id'] .')">
              <li class="fas fa-trash-alt"></li>
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>';
      }

  echo $tabla.$datosTabla.'</tbody></table>';

?>
```

Esa es la tabla, ahora el problema que tengo es como hacer que 3 `select` se guarden en la base de datos y la tabla pinte esos datos guardados

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";



CREATE TABLE `alumnos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `matricula_alumno` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_alumno` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;



CREATE TABLE `carreras` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_carrera` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;


CREATE TABLE `examen` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ordinario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `r1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `r2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ra` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;



CREATE TABLE `grupo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grupo` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;



CREATE TABLE `materias` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_materia` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE `profesores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_profesor` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `matricula_profesor` int(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;



CREATE TABLE `unidades` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unidad_1` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `unidad_2` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `unidad_3` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `unidad_4` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `unidad_5` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;


ALTER TABLE `alumnos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `carreras`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `examen`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `grupo`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `materias`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `profesores`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `unidades`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `alumnos`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;


ALTER TABLE `carreras`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


ALTER TABLE `examen`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


ALTER TABLE `grupo`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


ALTER TABLE `materias`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


ALTER TABLE `profesores`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


ALTER TABLE `unidades`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Esa es la base de datos, ahora aquí están mis `select`

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="calificarModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Calificar</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form>
          <h1>Unidad</h1>
          <select id="unidad" name="unidad" >
              <option value="u1">Unidad I</option>
              <option value="u2">Unidad II</option>
              <option value="u3">Unidad III</option>
              <option value="u4">Unidad IV</option>
              <option value="u5">Unidad V</option>
          </select>
      </form>       
      <br>
      <form>
          <h1>Calificación</h1>
          <select id="calificacion" name="calificacion" >
              <option value="ocho">8</option>
              <option value="nueve">9</option>
              <option value="diez">10</option>
          </select>
      </form>
      <br>
      <form>
          <h1>Exámen</h1>
          <select id="examen" name="examen" >
            <option value="ordinario">Ordinario</option>
            <option value="r1">R1</option>
            <option value="r2">R2</option>
            <option value="ra">RA</option>
         </select>
      </form>             
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-warning">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Entonces necesito que esos datos del `select` se guarden todos con un botón guardar y que luego se pinten en sus respectivos campos en la tabla.

Espero se entienda mi duda y si necesitan mas información para ayudarme, por favor no duden en pedirla y muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Podrias metero todos los select y el boton guardar en un solo <form> y ponerle a cada uno el atributo `name="sunombre"` para identificarlos en la variable `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

Cambia este código `html`

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="calificarModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Calificar</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
     <form method="POST">
      <div class="modal-body">
           <h1>Unidad</h1>
            <select id="unidad" name="unidad" >

                <option value="u1">Unidad I</option>
                <option value="u2">Unidad II</option>
                <option value="u3">Unidad III</option>
                <option value="u4">Unidad IV</option>
                <option value="u5">Unidad V</option>

            </select>
       <br>   
           <h1>Calificación</h1>
            <select id="calificacion" name="calificacion" >
                <option value="ocho">8</option>
                <option value="nueve">9</option>
                <option value="diez">10</option>
            </select>
        <br>
           <h1>Exámen</h1>
            <select id="examen" name="examen" >
                <option value="ordinario">Ordinario</option>
                <option value="r1">R1</option>
                <option value="r2">R2</option>
                <option value="ra">RA</option>
            </select>
          
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" name="guardar" class="btn btn-warning">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
       
      </div>
      </form>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para identificar los valores enviados:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
  $valorSelectUnidad = $_POST['unidad'];
  $valorSelectCalificacion = $_POST['calificacion'];
  $valorSelectExamen = $_POST['examen'];

  echo ' clasificacion: $valorSelectCalificacion <br>
         Unidad :  $valorSelectUnidad <br>
         Examen :  $valorSelectExamen <br>
       ';
}
?>
```